# Mod_rewrite causes AJAX requests using a relative URL to fail

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Even though I'm aware there have been posts with similar questions before, I'd like to present an issue I've been struggling with for many hours now and can't seem to resolve.

On a website that has its URLs rewritten by the mod rewrite module:

`www.domain.com/index.php?page=one`

becomes

`www.domain.com/one/`

I'm making an AJAX request using JQUERY and a relative URL >>>>

```
$.get('views/ajax_page.php', { }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Obviously no problem as long as the URL in the browser's address bar is www.domain.com, but when the GET variable 'page' is not null, the script fails to find the file ajax_page.php and throws the AJAX error "404 not found".

I know I could get around this by using an absolute URL in the AJAX request, but since the same-origin policy causes the browser to throw the HTTP error 0 when the visitor omits the protocol when typing the website's address in the address bar, this is not watertight too.

What would be the best way to tackle either one of the aforementioned problems or, even better, both?
Many thanks for your support.

Comment: The solution is simply use a url that will work both with and without the mod rewrite, or fix it with the mod rewrite. There isn't much mystery involved here. The same origin issue you mentioned should be solved by redirecting all traffic to the same prototcol and subdomain rather than allowing whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your folder views at the root of your site?

if so, add a slash before views:

```
$.get('/views/ajax_page.php', { },

function(data) {

alert(data);

});
```

If not, i would suggest calling the current page with your ajax request and manage to call the ajax file in your back end...

Also, make sure that your htaccess access files before redirecting :

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, our pay is our reputation!

Answer (score 0):

When using relative paths it's always wise to add the [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to your html site header:

```
<base href='http://www.your-site-address-here.com'/>
```